# Select at least one checkbox in a complex form array angular

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have a reactive form which contain a list of checkboxes and if one of them is checked an input form will be displayed. **How can I add a validator to ensure that at least one checkbox should be selected**.

This is my component.ts :

```js
coveragestypes : Array<ItemPolicyModel>= 
[{id:'1', name :'type 1'},
{id : '2',name :'type 2'},
{id : '3',name :'type 3'},
{id:'4',name:'type 4'}]

      coveragesObject : any = null;
       policyForm = new FormGroup({
         coveragesObject : new FormArray([])
        })
     ngOnInit() {
          this.addCheckboxes();
      }
      addCheckboxes() {
    let formGroups: FormGroup[] = this.coveragestypes.map(coverage => {
      return new FormGroup({
         id: new FormControl(coverage.id),
         name: new FormControl(coverage.name),
         value: new FormControl("", Validators.pattern(/^-?(0|[1-9]\d*)?$/)),
         checked: new FormControl(false)
      });
     });
     this.coveragesObject =  new FormArray(formGroups);
     this.policyForm.setControl('coveragesObject', this.coveragesObject );
     }
```

And this is my component.html :

```html
    <div *ngFor="let coverage of coveragesObject.controls;let i = index; ">
    <div [formGroup]="coverage">
       <input type="checkbox" kendoCheckBox [formControl]="coverage.controls.checked" />
       {{coverage.controls.name.value}}        
      <ng-container *ngIf="coverage.controls.checked.value">
          <input type="text" [formControl]="coverage.controls.value" style="  height: 100%;max-height:10px;padding : 0.5rem 0.75rem; 
                                            border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.125);width: 40%;">
         <span style="position: absolute;padding : 0.05rem 0.25rem ;">£</span>
         <div *ngIf="coverage.controls.value.invalid"
              style="font-size: xx-small; color : red">
         {{ "newRepair.intake.policyInfo.ownrisk" | translate }}
         </div>
    </ng-container>
</div>
</div>
```

Can anyone help me, please?

Comment: Did my answer solve your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing you are looking for is custom form validator. Angular provides us with the option of creating and passing validator functions that will be triggered on form changes.

Lets say for simplicity we have a `FormArray` containing `FormControl`-s with boolean values, that represent checkboxes, the thing that we should do is as follows

```js
...
// Our form
form = new FormGroup({
    boxes: new FormArray(
      [],
      // Pass custom validator that will check if the array has one element with value `true` a.k.a. at least one checked
      c => {
        const atLestOneChecked = (c as FormArray).controls.find(
          x => x.value === true
        );
        if (atLestOneChecked) {
          return {};
        }
        return { error: true };
      }
    )
 });
 ...
 ngOnInit(){
    // Populate form
    new Array(10).fill(null).forEach(() => {
      (this.form.get("boxes") as FormArray).push(new FormControl(false));
    });
 }
```

So what had i done here is passing a function as second argument to the `new FormArray()`, this function will be called each time when there are changes related to the `FormArray` references and based on the check if there is any `FormControl` with value `true` inside of the `FormArray` i am atachinng or clearing the erroros associated with the `FormArray`.

Ther few important things that i didnt discussed but you need to know when creating validators:

First you should always return error object
Second you can pass a single validator or an Array of validators
Third if you need async validators (for example validation based on BE response) you need to use the `AsyncValidators`

Here is a working [stackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/form-array-with-at-least-one-value?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)